# "Read .JSON file" methods in unity C# that also work with IOS and Android platforms

Tags: c#, android, ios, json, unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and stuck with reading .json file from previous few days. There are a lot of threads and methods which explain this but every time I tried anyone of them , it worked perfect on Unity editor but in IOS and Android devices it don't load data. I tried

1 - SimpleJSON from [here](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON)

2 - I also tried to use .plist file to save my data(which is in form of dictionary) and convert its extension to .txt as .plist does not work on IOS , I used PList parser given on this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/406235/A-Simple-PList-Parser-in-Csharptp)

to read plist but again it worked for unity editor but not for android and IOS devices.

Now while I'm searching around , there are a number of methods like **LitJSON** **FXJSON** etc. But before trying them , I just want to ask if anyone know about a method which also work for IOS and Android devices. Can anyone list the ways to read JSON file that work with IOS and Android... Thank YOu.

Addition : On XCode it's giving me following error , it does not load .JSON file.

[image]

Code which I've used to read file is following :

```
string jsn;
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("Assets/Resources/FoodStore.json")) 
{
    jsn = r.ReadToEnd ();
} 
JsonData jsonBooks = JsonMapper.ToObject(jsn);
```

Comment: I don't know about it. Is it in C#? Can you provide me with some useful link?

Comment: [json.net](http://www.json.net)

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to try it out.

Comment: There's also MiniJSON. Works great on mobile. https://gist.github.com/darktable/1411710

Comment: MiniJSON also not working. Is there any issue regarding file placement? as I've placed MiniJSON script in Assets/Scripts folder and my .json file in Assets/Resources. Again it's working fine on Unity editor. @VenkatatAxiomStudios. Do I need to install anything other , other than including MiniJSON script in my Scripts folder? Or there is something to do with plugins folder?

Comment: I've personally used it in a ton of projects and it does work. Can you post some code? It's possible that there's some issue there.

Comment: @VenkatatAxiomStudios I've added code and screen shot of error in question. Please have a look.

Comment: The assets folder doesn't exist in a build. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Assets` folder doesn't exist in a build. What you want to use is the [Resources.Load](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) function instead.

Try the code below

```
string jsn = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("FoodStore").text;  
JsonData jsonBooks = JsonMapper.ToObject(jsn);
```